# How to obtain list of added/deleted file among two revisions in mercurial through command line

Tags: mercurial

Modifications are required to be verified between two revisions r1 and r2 for added/modified files. Is there any way to get a list of added/deleted files alone, not modified files using a command such as hg diff or hg log or any other?

Answer (score 3):

I would use this template:

```
hg log -r r1:r2 --template "{rev}\nFiles added:\n\t{file_adds|nonempty}\nFiles removed:\n\t{file_dels|nonempty}\n\n"
```